# gigabyte z77x-d3h not recognising hdd in bios

Tags: hard-drive, sata, uefi

I have sata hdd and the bios is not recognising it. The hdd works as I have plugged it into a working pc and it appears. I have formatted in NTFS and run scandisk, no errors. is there any specific settings I need to change for this to work in the bios?

I connected the hdd to gsata and it works. however the dvdrive is not recognised on gsata. i have 2 sata3 ports and 4 sata2 ports.

**@aP0**

i think i have tried this already. i will try disableing hotplug again tonight. restore defaults disables the hotplug?

also my motherboard is ver1.0. how would i update the bios? i tried downlading the latest bios. extract it to usb. once i was in the bios i tried the qflash and then i don't see any option to select from usb drive.

I have updated the bios to F18i, still no difference. tried AHCI hot plug disabled and IDE, th eonly port that works is gsata0.

I have also tried taking the CMOS battery out. made no difference.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI and MBR or GPT I would be shocked if your motherboard was actually BIOS based

Comment: not sure what you mean. question updated

Comment: @Ramhound it is UEFI Dual Bios

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. If your "problem" is that your HDD is treated as a hot plug device, like a USB stick, which in Windows shows a icon to remove it safely, than you can either update your BIOS which I would recommend for these boards, to the latest version. I am using a Z77X-UD3H. Gigabytes work on the UEFI wasn't particularly good on this series.

AFAIK the early UEFI versions had this option enabled by default for every SATA Port.

If you do not want to update your UEFI, you can diasble the hot plug option for the SATA ports by going to the "System" Tab and then to "ATA Port Information". There you can disable for every port the hot plug functionality.

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: Make sure your USB Drive is FAT32 formatted. More information can be found in the manual. If it still won't work you can try installing the update in windows through gigabytes @BIOS Tool. You find it on the Gigabyte Homepage, the Page for your Motherboard in the download section.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: This is strange. The steps you took fixed the problem for me. Have you installed all needed drivers? Where are your drives pluged in? in the SATA ports used by the intel chip or the ones used by marvel? There is also a way to disable hot swap via the registry: [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/974023/fix-ahci-sata-drives-showing-in-safely-remove-hardware)

Comment: i have tried pluging in the hdd in all the sata ports and gsata ports. only gsata0 works.

Comment: Sorry, that it still does not work out for you. Maybe try updateing your drivers for the marvel and intel chip, meaning you need Intel Rapis Storage Technology Driver from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=%22Intel+Rapid+Storage+Technology+%28Intel+RST%29%22) and the marvel driver from the Gigabyte page. I do not know any thing more to suggest because troubleshooting it through the internet is not easy.

Comment: which one do i install and how would i do it from bios?

Comment: @sharif, those drivers are installed within windows.

Comment: how do i know which driver to install?

Comment: @sharif, the latest, the one on the top.

Comment: I gave up and bought new mobo